# Special aspect on a functor with left adjoint preserves limits by Mac Lane.

Tags: limits, category-theory, limits-colimits

In *Categories for the Working Mathematician* by **Mac Lane** he illustrated the fact that a functor with left adjoint preserves limits from the aspect on compositions of adjoints. (Page 119)

[image]

If $< F, G, \eta , \epsilon > : X \rightarrow A$ is a adjuntion and  limits of $T : J \rightarrow A$ exists. Then $G^J$ preserves limits $\lim T$.

Compositing the left and up, and the right and down adjunction respectively. Since $F^J \Delta = \Delta F$ $G \lim \cong \lim G^J$ (left adjoint to a given functor is unique up to isomorphism).

After proving $\lim G^J(T) = G \lim T$ we need to prove that the $G \tau$ is limiting cone where $\tau$ is the limiting cone of $A^J$.

Then Mac Lane said

> Put units and counits in the square diagram above, and recall that the limiting cone $\tau : a \rightarrow T$ is just the value of the counit of the adjunction $<\Delta, Lim, \dots> A \rightarrow A^J$ on the function $T$

What's this actually doing?

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1025345/right-ajoints-preserve-limits-alternate-proof) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1361243/a-proof-that-right-adjoints-preserve-limits) may help.